# KeystoneJS: "keystone.getResolvers is not a function" after deleting yarn.lock

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, keystonejs

I'm working on a KeystoneJS project.  I added hooks to one of my lists and the project worked fine.

When I was finished with my work I `pushed` my work to GitHub and made a pull request for my team. However GitHub complained about a security error (in `yarn.lock`), so I deleted `yarn.lock`, reinstalled `node_modules`(`yarn`).  When I ran the project again locally, however, I received the following error

```
✔ Validated project entry file ./tsout/index.js
✔ Keystone server listening on port 4545
✔ Initialised Keystone instance
✖ Connecting to database
TypeError: keystone.getResolvers is not a function
    at createApolloServer (/Users/r/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/app-graphql/lib/apolloServer.js:148:25)
    at GraphQLApp.prepareMiddleware (/Users/r/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/app-graphql/index.js:23:20)
    at /Users/r/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/lib/Keystone/index.js:752:17
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Keystone.prepare (/Users/r/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/lib/Keystone/index.js:751:12)
    at executeDefaultServer (/Users/r/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/bin/utils.js:112:42)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

It's throwing the error deep inside the keystone package in `node_modules`.  I deleted and reinstalled `node_modules`, I reverted my project to a commit from yesterday that worked fine, but I keep getting the same error.

What could the issue be?

### Edit

I tried going back to the already-working `develop` branch and same story.  Might it be something in `node_modules`?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an error with new package updates to KeystoneJS conflicting with my code.  When I removed `yarn.lock` and ran `yarn` it downloaded the latest versions.